# WPF: creating an app that looks like Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

How do you create a desktop application using C# that would look like Visual Studio 2010?

[Here's an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRNI8NO9VNQ)

- What development environments can you use?
- Can you recommend any samples, tutorials or blogposts?

**edit:**

I think I found what I was looking for... http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The video shows a plug-in for VS, but the basic answer is WPF.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to do it the way Visual Studio does.  Starting in 2010 the Visual Studio shell is a WPF application which has a very distinctive Win32 look and feel.  I believe, but don't know, that a lot of this is done via styling and themes.  So a simply WPF Application project would be the starting point of the solution.

Getting into applying styling and themes is beyond the scope of a simple SO answer.  Could you be a bit more specific about what you want?